# Magento2: Cash on delivery - how to get extra fee charge

Tags: magento2

I enable in backend option payment "cash on delivery".

I want to ask how to customize and add extra cost to customer basket for select payment "cash on delivery:".

https://prnt.sc/rqrnmj

Any solution?

```
sales ---> Payment methods   ---> cash on delivery [enable]
```

Is any way to display here https://prnt.sc/rqrpgv additional field with extra fee charge?

Answer (score 1):

Create file in your module `etc/adminhtml/system.xml` with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
            <group id="cashondelivery">
                <field id="extra_fee" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="65" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Extra Fee Charge</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Result: 
[image: Extra Fee Charge]

Comment: Which module is responsible for Cash On Delivery / shipping options in backend? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Magento_OfflinePayments

Comment: Can you please let me  know with path, where is located this module? I try find on vendor/magento but I do not see. Thank you

Comment: vendor/magento/module-offline-payments
or
app/code/Magento/OfflinePayments

Comment: Ok I found it. Thank you. Let me check

Comment: Can you please check after this changes your basket working correct? Because we have loading still... https://prnt.sc/rqvclf